# Увеличение высоты сайта при открытии спойлера

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Использую тег `details` при создании спойлера. Под ним открываются картинки, расположенные по вертикали. При открытии, спойлер закрывает собой оставшийся контент. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать так, чтобы при открытии спойлера увеличивался блок с картинками, не затрагивая оставшийся контент.

```css
.block {
  background-image: url("../img/3_bg.png");
  height: 100%;
}
.spoiler {
  background-color: gray;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="block">
  <details class="spoiler">
    <img src="img/screen/9.jpg" height="400" />
    <img src="img/Screen/8.jpg" height="400" />
    <img src="img/Screen/7.jpg" height="400" />
  </details>
</section>
```

Comment: Очевидно ваш блок имеет position:absolute. Нужно найти этот стиль в css и убрать.

Comment: Нет, стоит: position:relative;

Comment: @Kira приведите пример кода.

Comment: @Vadizar привела

Comment: Данный вопрос закрыть по причине "Не по теме" → "Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой.".

Answer (score 0):

Ваш код работает как надо, смотрите:

```css
.a {
   background-image: url("../img/3_bg.png");
   height: 100%;
}


.b{
   background-color: gray;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
   position:relative;
}
```

```html
<section class="a">
    <details class="b"> 
        <img src="img/screen/9.jpg" height="400" />

        <img src="img/Screen/8.jpg" height="400" />

        <img src="img/Screen/7.jpg" height="400" />                             
    </details>
</section>

123
```

Если [проблема не воспроизводится](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), мы никак не сможем помочь